# Looking for options other than MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, django, database-design, key-value

Previously I have set up a Django with MySQL attached for all of my projects.  I am looking into trying something different for this next project though.  What I need for it to do is for the client to be able to store a string, username, and timestamp.  Then for another client to be able to download all the latest of these records after a certain time.  I could do it with Django but it feels like there is too much setup for such a task.  What I am looking for is some database or web app that is really easy to set up that I can make a bunch of http request to to store the data and then make an http request to get all the data from a certain point onward.  What are some other solutions for doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) is a ["micro"framework](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/foreword/#what-does-micro-mean) - something simple and to the point, when you don't need all the batteries that come with a full stack framework like django.

Their hello world example should give you an idea of how easy it is:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello World!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

As for data storage, you have several options, here three that I am familiar with:

1. SQLite - now bundled with Python. Single file-based db.
2. [Redis](http://redis.io/) - a very fast key-value store
3. [Riak](http://basho.com/products/riak-overview/) - another popular db alternative

You can also go with other document-based dbs like Couch and Mongo.

Comment: Why the downvote? Cut the guy some slack, it's a perfectly valid and honest answer. At least tell what is wrong and let him update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try [cherrypy](http://cherrypy.org/) or [pyramid](http://readthedocs.org/docs/pyramid/en/latest/index.html)

Those really good to try.

Answer (score 0):

CherryPy is just great. Use it with NoSQL database like MongoDB or CouchDB. All you need can be done in just a few lines.